# Is SU the best place for this outdoor wireless connection question?

Tags: support, superuser, serverfault

This isn't an admin question, but deals with potentialy pro level gear that sys admins would encounter in advanced network setups with building wireless bridges. Would this be good to ask at SF instead or should I keep it on SU? SF might have some more knowlegdable people in this area as this request moves out of most home consumer wireless gear.

SU: https://superuser.com/questions/33077/what-hardware-antennae-to-use-for-an-outdoor-wireless-connection

SF: [What hardware (antennae) to use for an outdoor wireless connection?](https://serverfault.com/questions/60876/what-hardware-antennae-to-use-for-an-outdoor-wireless-connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't necessarily see a problem with it being on either site. I think you may have a potentially greater audience of users who know what the heck they are talking about on ServerFault, however.

I should also note that our office recently did something very similar for a client of ours (connecting a detached portion of their machine shop to their main building) wirelessly, so it could certainly fall under ServerFault's mission statement as well as just a high end consumer job.

Comment: That is exactly what my thoughts were.

Comment: and TheTXI gets downvoted again... haha

Comment: Go figure, right?

Answer (score 1):

If this is for home use and you're looking to use low-end consumer gear to get the job done, that's more SU. If it's for business, and you're looking for a commercial-grade solution, that's SF.

Comment: I would use home gear if that was possible, but I think pro gear is required for this kind of distance, reliability, and speed.

Comment: Ya, business is a different story, so for home use, I would go to SU.  For example, in a business environment, using technology that uses licensed frequencies is a good possibility, in a home environment, probably not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SU material to me.  While it could conceivably be of interest to some systems/network admin somewhere, that's hypothetical.  On the other hand, it is definitely computer-related.  The "prosumer" reference seems to map well to the core concept of SuperUser knowledge.