# Consolidate my userpage, notifications, etc on SO, SF, SU

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts

I'd like to have a one-stop-shop where I can see all my questions and answer. Having to login in three different places and have to check three different pages to see if I have answers and/or comments is too much time consuming. Would it be possibile to consolidate them? If you are wondering, I really don't like the separation among SO SF and SU at all, for questions searches, etc (see [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26934/is-the-separation-between-so-sf-su-too-harsh))

NOTE: don't answer use tabbed browsing or email notification, because they would only increase the clutter and the time spent in "checking"! The purpose of this request is to **reduce** this mess.

Comment: Very similar request to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29382/stack-aggregation

Comment: Similar, but not the same. I don't care about API or RSS or build my own pages at all. I'd just like to have those page consolidate, or "consolidable" easily.

Comment: Need 4 more votes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/587/single-location-for-so-sf-su-user-info

Comment: 4 votes for what?

Comment: To close this as dupe.

Comment: Need 3 more now.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, since I wrote that tabbed browsing (the answer of the other question) does not count.

Comment: @Davide: It doesn't matter if you like the answer or not, the *question* is the same.

Comment: @John, I'm amazed on how negligent and unable to listen you are. I didn't say that I don't **like** the answer, I said that it doesn't solve my problem. Effectively, it's like you are asking a question for windows on SO and I say "there is already the same question with an answer for linux, don't bother us". It's fair if you don't see this feature request as an useful one, but you cannot say that's has been already answered, because it has not

Comment: @Davide: R.E.A.D M.Y L.I.P.S: It is the S.A.M.E Q.U.E.S.T.I.O.N! If you do not get your answer there, what make you think repeating this question would help?